# VBA search by property in own type. Property as string

Tags: vba

I have own type (class module) named stdFastenersScrews, which have many properties, for example Diameter, Length, Supplier, etc...

I have loaded all screws in one Collection of stdFastenersScrews.

Now I'm trying to create search function, which returns new Collection based on search condition, but I don't know, how to transfer search condition (string) into stdFastenersScrews Property name. I tried something like this, but of course, it doesn't works...

```
Public screws As Collection

Public Sub parseScrews()
    Set screws = New Collection
    '...
    ' Here are parsed data from Excel into screws collection
    '...
    Dim searchResult As Collection
    Set searchResult = searchScrews("Diameter=3")
End Sub

Public Function searchScrews(condition As String) As Collection
    Dim results As Collection: Set results = New Collection

    Dim cond() As String: cond = Split(condition, "=")

    If screws.Count > 0 Then
        Dim screwData As stdFastenersScrews
        For Each screwData In screws
            If screwData.cond(0) = cond(1) Then
                results.Add screwData
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Cannot found any data about screws", vbInformation + vbOKOnly)
    End If

    Set searchScrews = results
End Function
```

Above I have line

```
If screwData.cond(0) = cond(1) Then
```

which I wish to VBA takes as screwData.Diameter (because cond(0)="Diameter") and I'm really don't know, how to do this. Do you have any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could add `searchScrews()` as a method of your class:

```
Public Function searchScrews(condition As String, screwsColl As Collection) As Collection
    Dim results As Collection: Set results = New Collection
    Dim cond() As String: cond = Split(condition, "=")
    Dim var As Variant

    If screwsColl.Count > 0 Then
        Dim screwData As stdFastenersScrews
        For Each screwData In screwsColl
            Select Case cond(0)
                Case "Diameter"
                    var = screwData.Diameter
                Case "Length"
                    var = screwData.Length
                Case "Supplier"
                    var = screwData.Supplier
                Case Else
                    Exit Function
            End Select
            If var = cond(1) Then results.Add screwData
        Next
    Else
        Call MsgBox("Cannot found any data about screws", vbInformation + vbOKOnly)
    End If

    Set searchScrews = results
End Function
```

and then use it in your "main" code:

```
    Dim searchResult As Collection
    Dim stdScrew As New stdFastenersScrews '<--| declare a variable of your class and get a new instance of it, so that you can call its methods
    Set searchResult = stdScrew.searchScrews("Diameter=3", screws) '<--| call your class method
```

this may not be the most elegant solution, but it should keep things consistent at least, since your class also holds the rules to query its own properties

Comment: @PetrKateřiňák, did you get through it?